# Deducing sinusoidal expression for V

Tags: ac, waveform

I have the question "An alternating voltage V has a periodic time of 20ms and a maximum value of 200v. When time t = 0, V = -75 volts.
Deduce a sinusoidal expression for V and sketch one cycle of the voltage showing important point."

So I know that:

time t = 20ms 
Max value = 200V
angular value = \$2{\pi}f\$, f = 1/T = 1/20 = 0.05.
Therefore angular value = 0.314

But the solutions say that the expression should be:

V = 200sin(10\$\pi\$t - 0.384) V

I'm not sure how this is achieved. I understand the maximum value which is given as 200 but not how the rest was achieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\$V(t) = \hat{V}Sin(\omega t + \theta) \$

So we know \$\hat{V}\$ = 200

We know T = 20ms -> f = 50Hz -> \$\omega = 100\pi \$

if V(t) = -75 when t=0

\$V(0) = -75 = 200Sin(\theta) \$

\$\theta = Sin^{-1}(-75/200) = - 0.384\$

main expression = \$V(t) = 200Sin(100\pi t- 0.384) \$

Comment: But the solutions say that it should be 10 pi and not 100 pi is there a possible mistake in the solutions ? :)

Comment: I would say so. 2*pi*50 = 100pi not 10pi

Answer (score 0):

The angles in the cycle, or period, at which the voltage is at -75, is, I believe 202.02431 degrees or 337.97569 degrees. Should not the last term in the answer, as given by JonRb as 0.384 - be - 0.375?